# Boot and Trunk Tag Synonym

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Could we please get the [boot](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boot) placed as a synonym to [trunk](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trunk)? Nothing against the European way of thinking ... there's just five questions under [trunk](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trunk) and two under [boot](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boot). Trunk seems the obvious lead choice, but the two of them outstanding is confusing.

Comment: Aside from bit obviously being the lead choice :-) I heartily agree with this!

Comment: @RoryAlsop - Hey, I was just going by the numbers here ;-)

Comment: And I was just going by being funny :-)

Comment: I'm with Rory on this ;-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop - And I wasn't?? Man, I gots to work on my delivery!

Comment: I vote for trunk. Boot is something you use to smash the accelerator into the floor.

Comment: We could put boot in the tag wiki, since many Europeans would be at a loss to know why a car would have an elephant trunk on it.

Comment: It's 'trunk' as in 'crate with a hinged lid.'

Comment: @anonymous2 - It's actually already in there. Been there since the beginning of this year.

Comment: See? Cars DO have trunks --> https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~mllee/cars/cacar007.JPG

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I took care of it. Boot -> Trunk

Comment: Thanks ... that's much better than "boot -> rear", so it's appreciated :o)